# how to write a .js file to a path using fs.writeFileSync

Tags: node.js, fs

```
fs.writeFileSync(tempPath, JSON.stringify(abc), "utf8");
```

The above sample is writing abc (a `.json` format data) to a file specified at `tempPath`.

My question is if the abc is a `.js` format file, how to use `fs.writeFileSync` to write to `file` at `tempPath`. Or use any other method.

Many thanks!

Comment: So you don't need to call JSON.stringify

Comment: but in my new file (at tempPath location), it only has [object Object]. I was expecting to see the .js data all copied over.

Comment: `abc` is a JavaScript object - to write that to a file you will always need to convert it to a string.

Comment: What's determining the value of `abc`? If you're seeing `[object Object]` in the file, then `abc` likely is already a string before this (`Object().toString() === '[object Object]'`).

Comment: It is just able to write text and binary. Could you show your  "new file" object data structure?

Comment: module.exports = {
    "sauce": {
      "selenium_host": "sauceblah",
      "selenium_port": 1111,
      "username": "",
      "access_key": "",
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "",
        "platform": "",
        "version": ""
      },
      "selenium": {
        "start_process": false
      }
    }
};

Comment: thank you Dong, the file that I would like to copy over is a .js formate file, it looks like:

module.exports = {
    "sauce": {
      "selenium_host": "sauceblah",
      "selenium_port": 1111,
      "username": "",
      "access_key": "",
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "",
        "platform": "",
        "version": ""
      },
      "selenium": {
        "start_process": false
      }
    }
};